# Using Copyrighted Characters in Portfolio?

Tags: copyright, legal, portfolio

I've seen numerous design portfolios online that involve characters from movies, TV, games, you name it.

I'm building a portfolio and for one project I was thinking of creating a few mobile UI screens of a Star Wars "character database" app that would show an image of a few characters and possibly a brief description of each. I never intend to build the app, just a simple design.

As of late Dribbble has been full of fan art, UIs, animations, etc. involving Star Wars. I'd imagine it would be okay as long as there's no profit from the work/design, but just wanted to check in and see what most people would say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is common--especially in student portfolios where a lot of your work would be hypothetical.

Do note that while it's fun to design what you like, also keep in mind that everyone thinks that...so consider trying to come up with work that may not be the trendiest subject matter at the time, as odds are a lot of student portfolios will have the same theme.

Comment: I read it as an ethical question, whether it is ok to use copyrighted characters for non profit purpose. But he builds a portfolio for his own profit - doesn't he? He doesn't earn money directly.

Comment: @userunknown Yea, there could be an ethical debate here, though I'm leaving that up to the individual. I'm merely pointing out that it's not uncommon. Personally, if it's clearly shown as student work, I'm fine with it form an ethical standpoint.